# Newton's method at log scale

Tags: calculus, analysis

For a set of system of equations
$$f_i(\vec{x})=0$$
The newton's method was
$$\vec{x}_{n+1}=\vec{x}_{n} -(J_{f_i}(\vec x_n)) \vec{f}_i(\vec x_n)$$
where $J_{f_i}(\vec x_n)$ was the Jacobian of $\vec{f}_i$.

However, if $f_i(\vec{x})$ was a set of polynomial, such as
$$
f_1= x+x^2+x^3+...+x^N
$$
and that $x$ was bounded $\vec x>\vec 0$

It it possible to evaluate the Newton's method at logarithmic scale?

Comment: what do you mean by "evaluate [...] at log scale"? Do you want to apply a log transformation on the inputs or outputs? If so, why not? Simply apply the chain rule for differentiation. (Not that you get any convergence guarantees)

Comment: @FelixB. In practice, i.e. $10\cdot x^100|_{x=100}$ may be a large value, so when computing the Jacobian or the $\vec f_i(\vec x_n)$ itself would lead to large numerical or symbolic values. But in the log scale $\log(10\cdot x^{100}\pm...|_{x=100} )$ might be a rather small number such as $10000$, and, if the $(J_{f_i} (\vec x_n) \vec f_i(\vec x_n) $ could be evaluated at log scales, this could resolve the stability issues and the newton's gradient could converge at exp speed.